# JQuery dialog opens collapsed

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net-3.5, jquery-dialog

I wrote this code implemented in a much bigger solution. the point was to add an asp:ImageButton to an asp:GridView. Clicking this image button would trigger a javascript call to a JQuery dialog.

This dialog is bound to a div containing an asp:BulletedList.

Simple enough, and I got it to work, but when I click the button and the dialog opens, it shows up collapsed to only the title bar. I can resize and expand the window to show the contents but I'd like it to open to the right size from the get go.

Setting the Resizable option to false just blocks it in collapsed mode and I can't see the data anymore. Also, opening the source code from the rendered page in IE displays an empty div (the div used by the dialog) while the dialog is collapsed to the title bar, but after I expand the window and display my BulletedList data, displaying the source code by right clicking the bullet list still shows an empty div...

Here is the code, the gridview is a lot bigger and item templates are used because each column has a specific header and footer but I took out all the non-related stuff.

## .ascx file

#### The Javascript:

```js
function ShowReferedTasks() {
    $('#litReferedTasks').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        minHeight: 150,
        minWidth: 500,
        resizable: true
    });
}
```

#### The gridview containing the button that triggers the dialog:

```html
<ext:GridView ID="gvTaskParameters" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="TaskParameterID"
    ShowFooter="<%# _isAdmin %>" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" ShowFooterWhenEmpty="True"
    EmptyDataText="Aucun paramètre disponible" AllowPaging="True" 
    PagerSettings-Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" 
    OnPageIndexChanging="gvTaskParameters_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvTaskParameters_RowCancelingEdit"
    OnRowEditing="gvTaskParameters_RowEditing" OnRowDeleting="gvTaskParameters_RowDeleting"
    OnRowUpdating="gvTaskParameters_RowUpdating" OnRowCommand="gvTaskParameters_RowCommand"
    OnRowDataBound="gvTaskParameters_RowDataBound" 
    OnDataBound="gvTaskParameters_DataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibViewTasks" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="ViewTasks"
                    ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="../../js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom/development-bundle/demos/images/icon-docs-info.gif" AlternateText="<%$ resources:resource, images_VoirTaches %>"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TaskParameterID") %>' />
                <%--<input id="ibViewTasks" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="image" src="../../js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom/development-bundle/demos/images/icon-docks-info.gif" value="button" />--%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</ext:GridView>
```

#### The div bound to the dialog:

```html
<div id="litReferedTasks" class="" title="Tâches Référées" style="background-color: White; position: absolute;">
    <div style="padding-left: 25px; padding-bottom: 25px; padding-right: 25px;">
        <asp:BulletedList ID="blReferedTasks" runat="server" DisplayMode="Text">
        </asp:BulletedList>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Code Behind in C#:

```cs
else if (e.CommandName == "ViewTasks")
            {
                TaskParameterMapManager mgr = new TaskParameterMapManager(DatabaseConnection);
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                var ts = mgr.GetTasks(id).OrderBy(t => t.TaskDescription);                

                this.blReferedTasks.DataSource = ts.ToList();
                this.blReferedTasks.DataTextField = "TaskDescription";
                this.blReferedTasks.DataBind();

                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Key_ShowReferedTasks", "ShowReferedTasks();", true);                
            }
```

Comment: This is a client-side question involving HTML + JavaScript + jQuery. Your server-side C# source code is not helpful in solving the problem

Comment: That was just to give you a general idea of how it is implemented. I'm also pretty sure the problem lies with JQuery but I haven't got a clue. Also since the C# is the code calling the JS function and not the imagebutton, it seemed a little bit relevant.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb, as I've only glanced but I notice the div your putting into the dialog has an inline style position absolute. It could be that cause of that the dialog can't find the dimensions of the contents within to resize the dialog accordingly, as I think the dialog itself is also absolute. In that, your in a sense creating float like elements that are dettached from the rest of the DOM

Comment: Thanks @chris, that was it. Simple mistake but hours wasted looking for the answer. At least I'll remember it now. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, can't say how many of my questions here on stack have been due to similar small easily over looked mistakes. So I know the feeling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was, as @chris suggested, to remove the "position:absolute" style tag in the div used by the dialog.